# GPG SmartCard (YubiKey) Private Key Export

Tags: gnupg, gpg4win

I'm using GPG4Win on Windows, with a YubiKey 4.

I generated the keys using the --card-edit prompt, so they should (AFAIK) have never left the card.

Using PuTTy integration, it works great for SSH authentication.

I was under the impression that you shouldn't be able to export the private key if it is safely stored on the smart card (YubiKey), as crypto operations are handed off to the cards onboard processor to avoid it leaving.

However, if I open Kleopatra the GPG4Win GUI, right click on my key and "export secret key", it will quite happily export my private key un-encrypted.

I feel this kind of defeats the object of the security around the token - what am I doing wrong?

I hadn't even entered the admin PIN, only the standard PIN as I'd been using it to authenticate via SSH.

If this is expected behaviour, what is to stop and attacker dumping the key in the background from my PC when the token is plugged in? It didn't even prompt for any kind of further authorization.

Comment: OpenPGP smart cards don't allow to export secret keys, also the YubiKey doesn't. Have you had a look at what's exported? Whatever it is, it cannot be a working private OpenPGP key.

Comment: Thanks Jens, you are right - it looks exactly like a private key export, but it is just garbage, as it does exactly the same if the smart-card isn't connected. I was expecting it to say it was impossible, rather than export nonsense.

Comment: See [this answer on StackExchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/108190/export-secret-key-after-yubikey-is-plugged-in) for a detailed explanation.

Comment: secret keys on smartcard (listed with >), can not be exported. You can export with --export-secret-keys, but all you get is public key only.